# Outlook Web Access v8 doesn't work in Internet Explorer 10/11

Tags: microsoft-outlook, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11, outlook-web-access

Outlook Web Access is frozen /  not interactive in Internet Explorer 10; the usual main screen listing e-mails in the inbox is visible but clicking on links and buttons has no discernible effect at all. I have no such problem in Firefox or in Internet Explorer 8.

So far I have tried adding the domain to the list of trusted sites, and turning down my security settings. Neither has had any effect. There is no obvious indication of, for example, pop-ups being blocked.

EDIT: NB - the version of Outlook Web Access in play was version 8.3

EDIT: NB2 - this is also an issue, perhaps not surprisingly, for users of IE11.

Comment: Have you tried compatibility mode?

Comment: I clicked on the 'broken page' icon in the address bar to activate compatibility mode and OWA started working immediately. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @Pretzel you should add this as an answer so that it becomes searchable and get voted up and stuff :)

Comment: Done and done..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try activating compatibility mode in IE10. To do so, simply click the icon that looks like a broken page on the right hand side of your address bar. It allows old or "obsolete objects" to function in the newer version of IE.

A similar approach works in IE11 - click on the cog icon and click on 'Compatibility View Settings', then add the site to the list.

Comment: Thank you Pretzel. This is an 'obvious' answer but a very helpful one. It didn't occur to me to try 'compatibility mode' since I was using a Microsoft browser on a Microsoft web product! Also, this answer had not been previously offered on any of the forums I looked at. So in a small way we have made the world a happier place :-)

Comment: Haha, no problem. Sometimes you just think a problem can't be so simple.

Comment: @user39951 - The reason OWA didn't work was IE10 was released after the version of OWA your using.  Later revisions of Outlook won't have this problem.

Comment: Yes - I was on OWA version 8.3 - have updated the Question with this information, and the OWA tag.